# d3py installation error - no module named pandas_figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, d3.js

I have problems installing d3py.

easy_install from https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py/tarball/master says it's all ok, cloning the repo and setup.py'ing say it's all ok as well, Pandas an Numpy works great (I also use Networkxs working good as well), bu when I try to import d3py come this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\whoauser\Desktop\python\sofia\sofia.py", line 2, in     <module>
    import d3py
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\d3py-0.2.3-py3.4.egg\d3py\__init__.py", line 1, in   <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas_figure'
```

Is this a bug in the installation script? Where I can find a working egg?
Do anyone had the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the pandas module for python. Have you done that?

Comment: yes, pands and numpy are installed correctly (I can import them).

Comment: After some deep digging in the net I think that's a compatibility issue.. Python 3.4 seems to not be supported. -- Tried to install d3py on python 2.7 and it works...

Comment: Yeah, a lot of packages aren't compatible with python3 yet (maybe someday).